# Model Screen does not pop up when i submit form using React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've made a react mini project about creating a nft with a form attached when the form gets approved a mini pop up occurs for approval , minting , sign and lock.

The pop up doesnt appear don't know why or where am i mistaken. can anyone help me with this , greatly appreciated!

Here's my code so far for this stuff as of this moment when i click on create console.log doesn't print

```
  const [showmodal, setshowmodal] = useState(false);
  const [showbid, setShowbid] = useState(false);
  const [accounts, setaccount] = useState("");


 const handleFormSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submit")
      setaccount(address); //
      if (validateSingle()) { // validateSingle is form verification about fields 
        setShowbid(true);
      }
     
       <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} id="form-create-item" className="form-border"  encType="multipart/form-data">
                  <div className="field-set">
                      <h5>Upload file</h5>
                      <div className="d-create-file">
                          <p id="file_name">PNG, JPG, GIF, WEBP or MP4. Max 200mb.</p>
                          {files.map(x => 
                          <p key="{index}">PNG, JPG, GIF, WEBP or MP4. Max 200mb.{x.name}</p>
                          )}
                          <div className='browse'>
                            <input type="button" id="get_file" className="btn-main" value="Browse"/>
                            <input id='upload_file' type="file"  className="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple onChange={handleFile} />
                          </div>
                          
                      </div>
                      <div className="row" style={{paddingTop:30}}>
                        <div md={8} sm={8} xs={8}>
                          <label>Put</label>
                          <p className="para-color">
                            Receive Bid
                          </p>
                      </div>
                      <div md={4} sm={4} xs={4} className="text-right">
                      <Toggle
                        onClick={onToggle}
                        on={<h2>On</h2>}
                        off={<h2>Off</h2>}
                        size="xs"
                        offstyle="danger"
                        active={toggleActive}
                      />
                      </div>
                        {toggleActive === true ? (
                         <div className="form-row">
                          <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                          <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                            <span
                              type="button"
                              className={
                                fixed === 1
                                  ? "nft_create_btn active"
                                  : "nft_create_btn"
                              }
                              onClick={Onfixed}
                            >
                              Fixed Price
                            </span>
                            <span
                              type="button"
                              className={
                                timed === 1
                                  ? "nft_create_btn active"
                                  : "nft_create_btn"
                              }
                              onClick={Ontimed}
                            >
                             Timed Price
                            </span>
                            <span
                              type="button"
                              className={
                                ongoing === 1
                                  ? "nft_create_btn active"
                                  : "nft_create_btn"
                              }
                              onClick={Auctiongoing}
                            >
                              Ongoing Auction
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    ) : (
                      ""
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <div className="row" style={{paddingTop:30}}>
                  <span md={8} sm={8} xs={8}>
                      <label>Unlock Once</label>
                      <p className="para-color">
                        Content Unlock
                      </p>
                    </span>
                    <span md={4} sm={4} xs={4} className="text-right">
                      <Toggle
                        onClick={onToggle2}
                        on={<h2>On</h2>}
                        off={<h2>Off</h2>}
                        size="xs"
                        offstyle="danger"
                        active={toggleActive2}
                      />
                    </span>

                  </div>
                  {toggleActive2 === true && (
                    <div className="mb-15" style={{paddingTop:15}}>
                      <div md={12}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control primary_inp"
                            id="digitalkey"
                            name="digitalkey"
                            onChange={onChangeunlock}
                            placeholder="Digital key,code to redeem or link to a file"
                          />
                          <span>Tip: Markdown syntax is supported</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  )}

                {toggleActive === true && fixed === 1 && (
                    <div className="mb-15">
                      <div md={12}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          {symbol == 'ETH' ? (
                            <label htmlFor="price" style={{color : "white"}}>
                             Instant Price{" "} ({symbol})
                          </label>
                          ) : (
                            <label htmlFor="price" style={{color : "white"}}>
                            Instant Price{" "} ({symbol})
                          </label>
                          )}
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control input-custom"
                            onChange={onChangeprice}
                            id="price"
                            name="price"
                            value={onchangeprice}
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  )}
                  {toggleActive1 === true && timed === 1 && (
                    <div className="form-row">
                      <div className="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label className="primary_label" htmlFor="desccription">
                          Date{" "}
                          <span className="text-muted"></span>
                        </label>
                        <div className="d-flex">
                          <DatePicker
                            className="form-control input-custom"
                            selected={startDate}
                            onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
                            selectsStart
                            startDate={startDate}
                            endDate={endDate}
                            dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy h:mm aa"
                            showTimeInput
                          />
                          <DatePicker
                            className="form-control input-custom"
                            selected={endDate}
                            onChange={(date) => setEndDate(date)}
                            selectsEnd
                            startDate={startDate}
                            endDate={endDate}
                            minDate={startDate}
                            dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy h:mm aa"
                            showTimeInput
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label className="primary_label" htmlFor="name">
                            Minimum Bid
                        </label>
                        <div className="input_group">
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control input-custom"
                            onChange={onChangebid}
                            id="minimumbid"
                            name="minimumbid"
                            placeholder="Minimum Bid"
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  )}
                      <div className="spacer-single"></div>

                      <h5>Title</h5>
                      <input type="text" name="item_title" id="name" className="form-control" placeholder="e.g. 'Crypto Funk"  onChange={onChange}/>

                      <div className="spacer-10"></div>

                      <h5>Description</h5>
                      <textarea data-autoresize name="item_desc" id="description" className="form-control" placeholder="e.g. 'This is very limited item'" onChange={onChangeDescription}></textarea>

                      <div className="spacer-10"></div>
                      <div className="mb-15">
                        <div md={12}>
                          <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="category" style={{color:"white"}}>
                              Category
                            </label>
                            <Select
                              className=""
                              id="tokenCategory"
                              onChange={HandleChange}
                              options={CategoryOption}
                            />
                          </div>
                         </div>
                       </div>
                      {/* <h5>Price in {symbol}</h5>
                      <input type="text" name="item_price" id="item_price" className="form-control"  /> */}

                      <div className="spacer-10"></div>

                      <h5>Royalties</h5>
                      <input type="text" name="item_royalties" id="royalties" className="form-control" placeholder="suggested: 0, 10%, 20%, 30%. Maximum is 70%" onChange={onChangeroy}/>

                      <div className="spacer-10"></div>

                      <input type="button" id="submit" value="Create Item"  className="connect-wallet create-item btn-main"/>
                  </div>
              </form>

//Modal pop up 
<Modal
        show={showbid}
        size="md"
        backdrop="static"
        onHide={handleClosebid}
        centered
        id="follow-steps-modal"
        className="custom-style-modal"
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>{language[localStorageLang].FOLLOW_STEPS}</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body className="pl-30 pr-30">
          <Row>
            <Col sm={2} md={2} className="col-xs-2">
              {approveprograss === false ? (
                <div className="follow-step-1-icon">
                  <i className="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="follow-step-2-icon">
                  <div className="loader"></div>
                </div>
              )}
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={6} className="col-xs-10">
              <div className="follow-step-1-content">
                <h4>{language[localStorageLang].APPROVE}</h4>
                <p className="para-color">
                  {language[localStorageLang].CHECKING_BALANCE}
                </p>
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col sm={4} md={4} className="col-xs-12">
              {approveprograss === false ? (
                <div>
                  {approvesuccess === false ? (
                    <div className="follow-step-1-button">
                      <Link to="#" onClick={approve} disabled>
                        {language[localStorageLang].TRY_AGAIN}
                      </Link>
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    <div>
                      {approvesuccess === true ? (
                        <div className="follow-step-1-button">
                          <Link to="#" disabled>
                            {language[localStorageLang].DONE}
                          </Link>
                        </div>
                      ) : (
                        <div className="follow-step-1-button">
                          <Link to="#" onClick={approve} className="">
                            {language[localStorageLang].START}
                          </Link>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="follow-step-2-button">
                  <Link to="#" className="">
                    {language[localStorageLang].INPROGRESS}
                  </Link>
                </div>
              )}
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col sm={12} md={12}>
              <hr />
            </Col>
          </Row>

          <Row>
            <Col sm={2} md={2} className="col-xs-2">
              {uploadprograss === false ? (
                <div className="follow-step-1-icon">
                  <i className="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="follow-step-2-icon">
                  <div className="loader"></div>
                </div>
              )}
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={6} className="col-xs-10">
              <div className="follow-step-2-content">
                <h4>{language[localStorageLang].UPLOAD}</h4>
                <p className="para-color">
                  {language[localStorageLang].CHECKING_BALANCE}
                </p>
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col sm={4} md={4} className="col-xs-12">
              {uploadprograss === false ? (
                <div>
                  {uploadsuccess === false ? (
                    <div className="follow-step-1-button">
                      <Link to="#" onClick={mintCalling} disabled>
                        {language[localStorageLang].TRY_AGAIN}
                      </Link>
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    <div>
                      {uploadsuccess === true ? (
                        <div className="follow-step-1-button">
                          <Link to="#" disabled>
                            {language[localStorageLang].DONE}
                          </Link>
                        </div>
                      ) : (
                        <div className="follow-step-1-button">
                          <Link to="#" onClick={mintCalling}>
                            {language[localStorageLang].START}
                          </Link>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="follow-step-2-button">
                  <Link to="#" className="">
                    {language[localStorageLang].INPROGRESS}
                  </Link>
                </div>
              )}
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col sm={12} md={12}>
              <hr />
            </Col>
          </Row>

          <Row>
            <Col sm={2} md={2} className="col-xs-2">
              {sellprograss === false ? (
                <div className="follow-step-1-icon">
                  <i className="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="follow-step-2-icon">
                  <div className="loader"></div>
                </div>
              )}
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={6} className="col-xs-10">
              <div className="follow-step-3-content">
                <h4>Sign sell order</h4>
                <p className="para-color">
                  {language[localStorageLang].CREATE_SIGNATURE}
                </p>
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col sm={4} md={4} className="col-xs-12">
              {sellprograss === false ? (
                <div>
                  {sellsuccess === false ? (
                    <div className="follow-step-1-button">
                      <Link to="#" onClick={signsell} disabled>
                        {language[localStorageLang].TRY_AGAIN}
                      </Link>
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    <div>
                      {sellsuccess === true ? (
                        <div className="follow-step-1-button">
                          <Link to="#" disabled>
                            Done
                          </Link>
                        </div>
                      ) : (
                        <div className="follow-step-1-button">
                          <Link to="#" onClick={signsell}>
                            {language[localStorageLang].START}
                          </Link>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="follow-step-2-button">
                  <Link to="#" className="">
                    {language[localStorageLang].INPROGRESS}
                  </Link>
                </div>
              )}
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col sm={12} md={12}>
              <hr />
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col sm={2} md={2} className="col-xs-2">
              {lockprograss === false ? (
                <div className="follow-step-1-icon">
                  <i className="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="follow-step-2-icon">
                  <div className="loader"></div>
                </div>
              )}
            </Col>
            <Col sm={6} md={6} className="col-xs-10">
              <div className="follow-step-3-content">
                <h4>{language[localStorageLang].SIGN_LOCK_ORDER}</h4>
                <p className="para-color">
                  {language[localStorageLang].SIGN_LOCK_WALLET}
                </p>
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col sm={4} md={4} className="col-xs-12">
              {lockprograss === false ? (
                <div>
                  {locksuccess === false ? (
                    <div className="follow-step-1-button">
                      <Link to="#" onClick={signlock} disabled>
                        {language[localStorageLang].TRY_AGAIN}
                      </Link>
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    <div>
                      {locksuccess === true ? (
                        <div className="follow-step-1-button">
                          <Link to="#" disabled>
                            {language[localStorageLang].DONE}
                          </Link>
                        </div>
                      ) : (
                        <div className="follow-step-1-button">
                          <Link to="#" onClick={signlock}>
                            {language[localStorageLang].START}
                          </Link>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="follow-step-2-button">
                  <Link to="#" className="">
                    {language[localStorageLang].INPROGRESS}
                  </Link>
                </div>
              )}
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
```

Let me know if anything else is required , was trying to resolve this since long time but unable to !

Comment: What does validateSingle() function returns?

Comment: its a validation for a form it will return a boolean value if form value is correct @abdullah ansari

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.